# qt odbc plugin build unsuccessful

Tags: qt, plugins, odbc

I developed an application along the lines of the SQL Browser example provided with QT in the Demos and Examples section. My development machine is Windows XP (visual studio compiler was used) and the application works well on it. It is able to connect to an external database (MySQL), and I am able browse through tables. I used the QODBC driver for connections. However when I deploy the executable (with all required .dll files) in another computer without QT, it says that I need to provide for the database drivers. I read the documentation and realized that I need to build a PlugIn for QODBC drivers. 
First I looked at an example Plugin (Echo Plugin Example) given at http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/tools-echoplugin.html. Then I followed the instructions in http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/sql-driver.html#qodbc.

```
cd %QTDIR%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\odbc
 qmake odbc.pro
 nmake
```

The above commands built `qsqlodbc4.dll`. However, I am not successful in developing a Plugin for my application. Here are my steps, and the compilation output:

1. Created project `odbcplugin.pro` (see script  below) under directory `/odbcpluginTest`

   > ```
   > TEMPLATE    = subdirs
   > SUBDIRS       = sqlbrowser \
   >               odbc
   > CONFIG += release
   > # install    
   > target.path = $$PWD
   > sources.path = $$PWD
   > sources.files = $$SOURCES $$HEADERS $$RESOURCES $$FORMS    
   > INSTALLS += target sources
   > ```
2. Created subdirectories: `/odbc, /sqlbrowser, /plugins`

### Inside the directroy `/odbcpluginTest /odbc/`

(i). Copied `odbc.pro` and suitably modified the paths and file names (for example, a file originally named as `main.cpp` has been renamed as `mainODBC.cpp` to avoid confusing with the file named `main.cpp` inside `/sqlbrowser`). See the scripts below:

> ```
> TEMPLATE        = lib
> INCLUDEPATH    += ../sqlbrowser
> SOURCES         = mainODBC.cpp
> TARGET          = qsqlodbc
> DESTDIR         = ../plugins
> CONFIG += release
> include(qsql_odbc.pri)
> include(qsqldriverbase.pri)
> sources.files = $$SOURCES $$HEADERS $$RESOURCES $$FORMS
> INSTALLS += target sources
> ```

(ii).  The file `odbcinterface.h` that describes the plugin interface is included as a header in `odbc.pro`. However, it is actually placed inside the directory `/sqlbrowser`. Hence, the line `INCLUDEPATH    += ../sqlbrowser` is included in the above script.

(iii). Also, copied all related project files (`qsql_odbc.pri, qsqldriverbase.pri, qpluginbase.pri, qt_targets.pri`). Suitably modified the paths in all project files (there may be mistakes in here).

(iv). The header (`qsql_odbc.h`) and source (`qsql_odbc.cpp`) files of `qsql_odbc.pri` have also been copied.

### Inside the directory `/odbcpluginTest /sqlbrowser/`

(i). Copied `sqlbrowser.pro` and all related files.

(ii). Created the header file `odbcinterface.h` that describes the plugin interface (see below) and added it to the HEADERS in `sqlbrowser.pro`.

```
#ifndef ODBCINTERFACE_H
#define ODBCINTERFACE_H
#include <QString>
#include <QtSql/qsqldriver.h>
class OdbcInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~OdbcInterface() {}
    virtual   QSqlDriver* create(const QString &) = 0;
    virtual   QStringList keys() const = 0;
};
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(OdbcInterface,
                    "developed similar to com.trolltech.Plugin.EchoInterface/1.0");
QT_END_NAMESPACE
#endif // ODBCINTERFACE_H
```

iii.    Also, modified the `browser.h` file by adding the lines

```
#include "odbcinterface.h"
private:
     bool loadPlugin();
    OdbcInterface *odbcInterface;
Public:
 void TestCase1();
```

iv. Also, modified the `browser.cpp` file by adding the function definitions:

```
bool Browser::loadPlugin()
{
    QDir pluginsDir(qApp->applicationDirPath());
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    pluginsDir.cdUp();
    pluginsDir.cdUp();
#endif
    pluginsDir.cd("plugins");
    foreach (QString fileName, pluginsDir.entryList(QDir::Files)) {
        QPluginLoader pluginLoader(pluginsDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName));
        QObject *pluginI = pluginLoader.instance();
        if (pluginI) {
            odbcInterface = qobject_cast<OdbcInterface *>(pluginI);
            if (odbcInterface)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Browser::TestCase1()
{
    loadPlugin();
    QStringList list;
    list = odbcInterface->keys();
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    if(list.length() >0)
    {
        msgBox.setText("Test1 success");
    }
    else
    {
        msgBox.setText("Test1 failure");
    }
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

### Testing:

In `browser.cpp` file,  the constructor `Browser::Browser(QWidget *parent)` was modified by appending a call to `void Browser::TestCase1()`

### Compile Output:

```
15:09:18: Running build steps for project odbcplugin...
15:09:18: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
15:09:18: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
cd sqlbrowser\ && C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -nologo -j 2 -f Makefile
C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -nologo -j 2 -f Makefile.Debug
cd odbc\ && C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -nologo -j 2 -f Makefile
C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -nologo -j 2 -f Makefile.Release
link /LIBPATH:"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\lib" /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"release\qsqlodbc.intermediate.manifest" /VERSION:4.81 /OUT:..\plugins\qsqlodbc4.dll @C:\DOCUME~1\SHAINE~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\qsqlodbc4.dll.5076.0.jom
Creating library ..\plugins\qsqlodbc4.lib and object ..\plugins\qsqlodbc4.exp
mainODBC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QODBCDriverPlugin::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QODBCDriverPlugin@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
mainODBC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall QODBCDriverPlugin::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QODBCDriverPlugin@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
mainODBC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall QODBCDriverPlugin::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QODBCDriverPlugin@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
..\plugins\qsqlodbc4.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
jom 1.0.6 - empower your cores
command failed with exit code 1120
command failed with exit code 2
command failed with exit code 2
15:09:19: The process "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project odbcplugin (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```